# what's this red line in firebug's layout panel?

Tags: css, firefox, layout, firebug

[image]

Comment: "belongs on superuser.com" Oh come on, you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain of this because I've deduced it from experimentation rather than looking at Firebug's source, but the red dotted line seems to just always line up with the ruler.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, they show the bottom and left extents of the ruler area - which always seem to line up with one of the element's parent's.

Comment: It's dashed, not dotted ;-)